Qml repeater model
i have an nested repeater in qml and i want to set the model of repeater dynamically but i can not set the index of my model in QML file.
this is my c++ class::
struct rField
{
    float rT;
    float rC;
};

enum eRcuRoles{
    RT = Qt::UserRole,
    RC
};




class SubArrayDataModel : public QAbstractListModel, public ISingleton<SubArrayDataModel>
{
    Q_OBJECT
    friend class ISingleton;
//    int counter;
public:

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap get(int row);
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) override;
    QMap<unsigned int , SubArrayRowDataModel> mapingRows;
    Q_INVOKABLE SubArrayRowDataModel* getModel(int row);


    void startReadData(Structures::Struct_RM rM);



    SubArrayDataModel();
    ~SubArrayDataModel();

public slots:


signals:

    void sgl_updateRows();

private:
    QList<rField> m_rData;
};






#include "SubArrayDataModel.h"

//****************************************************************************************************************

SubArrayDataModel::SubArrayDataModel()
{


    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        rField temp2;
        temp2.rT = i;
        temp2.rC = 2;
        m_rData.append(temp2);
        mapingRows.insert(i, SubArrayRowDataModel());
    }
}

SubArrayRowDataModel* SubArrayDataModel::getModel(int row)
{
    auto it = mapingRows.find(row);
    if(it != mapingRows.end())
        return &it.value();
}
//****************************************************************************************************************

QHash<int, QByteArray> SubArrayDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    roles[RT] = "rT";
    roles[RC] = "rC";

    return roles;
}

//****************************************************************************************************************

QVariant SubArrayDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    switch(role)
    {
    case eRcuRoles::RT:
        return m_rData[index.row()].rT;
        break;
    case eRcuRoles::RC:
        return m_rData[index.row()].rC;
        break;
    
    }
}

//****************************************************************************************************************

int SubArrayDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
            return m_rData.length();
}

//****************************************************************************************************************

bool SubArrayDataModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    //    rField data = m_rData.at(index.row());

    if(!index.isValid()) return false;
    if (role == RT){
        m_rcuData[index.row()].rT = value.toFloat();
        emit dataChanged(index , index , { RT });
        return true;
    }

    if (role == RCUCURRENT){
        //        m_rData[index.row()].rC = value.toFloat();
        m_rData[index.row()].rC = value.toFloat();
        emit dataChanged(index , index , { RC });
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}


//****************************************************************************************************************

QVariantMap SubArrayDataModel::get(int row)
{
    QHash<int,QByteArray> names = roleNames();
    QHashIterator<int, QByteArray> i(names);
    QVariantMap res;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        QModelIndex idx =  index(row, 0);
        QVariant data = idx.data(i.key());
        res[i.value()] = data;
    }
    return res;
}

//****************************************************************************************************************

void SubArrayDataModel::startReadData(Structures::Struct_RM rM)
{

    for (int i =0; i< m_rData.size()/*12*/;i++) {
        m_rData[i].rT = rM.rTM[i];
        //        m_rData[i].rT = 100;
        emit sgl_updateRows();
    }


    auto it = mapingRows.find(rM.rNum);
    std::cerr << "rNum::" << rM.rN << std::endl;
    srand(time(0));
    int test1;
    if(it != mapingRows.end())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        {
            //            std::cerr << "subArrayNum::" << i << std::endl;
            auto test = it.value().rowData();
            test1 = rand() % 30;
//            std::cerr << test1 << std::endl;
            it.value().rowData()[i].temp = test1 /*rand() % 30*/;

            it.value().rowData()[i].current = rM.pCMM[i]/*rand() % 30*/;
            QModelIndex index = this->index(i, 0);
            setData(index, QVariant::fromValue(it.value().rowData()[i].temp), temp);
            setData(index, QVariant::fromValue(it.value().rowData()[i].current), current);
            emit sgl_updateRows();
        }
//        std::cerr << "------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

}
//****************************************************************************************************************

SubArrayDataModel::~SubArrayDataModel()
{

}
//****************************************************************************************************************



and this is my qml file ::
Column{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 7 * rectMargin
        anchors.leftMargin: 10 * rectMargin

        Repeater{
            id: rowRepeater
            model: subArrayDataModel.getModel(rowRepeater.index)
            Item{

                id: rcu



                property int columnPadding : 3
                property int columnSpacing : 2
                property var rcuTemp: subArrayDataModel.get(index).rT
                property var rcuCur: subArrayDataModel.get(index).rC

                Row{
                    
                    spacing: 2
                    Repeater{
                        model: rowRepeater.model

                        delegate: Rectangle{
                            id: tr
                            property alias Current : rCurrent
                            property alias Temperature : rTemperature
                            width: rcu.trWidth
                            height: rcu.trHeight
                            anchors.leftMargin: rectMargin
                            color: model.color

                            Connections {
                                target: subArrayDataModel
                                function onSgl_updateRows() {
                                     rTemperature.text = temp.toFixed(1)
                                }
                            }


                            Column{
                                spacing: rcu.columnSpacing / 2
                                topPadding: rcu.columnPadding / 2
                                leftPadding: rcu.columnPadding


                                Row{

                                    Text{
                                        id: rTemperature
                                        text: model.temp.toFixed(1)
                                        color: "white"
                                        font.pixelSize: 14
                                        font.family: "TrulyMadlyDpad"
                                    }
                                    Text{
                                        text: qsTr("\u2103") + translator.emptyString
                                        color: "white"
                                        font.pixelSize: 14
                                        font.family: "TrulyMadlyDpad"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }



i pass the model data from C++ to the qml but in qml in line ::
model: subArrayDataModel.getModel(rowRepeater.index)
i get the 0 for the index In the event that i have 12 model and should get 0 to 11 index but my model do not updated and get the repeated data for qml

I think the problem is that you provide your data to QML through getModel Q_INVOKABLE method. In this case QML won't get notification about the changes. You may want to try create a Q_PROPERTY instead with NOTIFY as well and provide that as model to the Repeater.
